# htaccess deny access to all php files except specific one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following htaccess rules are given and set by the server management application:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-content">
<FilesMatch \.php$>
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

This is actually fine except the fact that it should exclude a specific file which must be accessible:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/image.php
```

Do you have an idea how to adjust the first rules to exclude the mentioned file from being blocked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could add one more FilesMatch condition that then allowed access to your file.

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-content">

 <FilesMatch \.php$>
  Require all denied
 </FilesMatch>

 <FilesMatch image\.php$>
  Require all granted
 </FilesMatch>

</Directory>
```

This should work just fine.
Hope it helps.

If you want to look at more information about Apache configuration sections, take a look at their main documentation portal.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with below,

```
<FilesMatch !image\.php$>
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```